# Can Gtk TextView widget go in error if i pass some charachter?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, textview, gtk#

I'm developing a simple karaoke application with C#, Mono and GTK sharp.
The problem is that when i run some karaoke and i redirect the output to myTextView.Buffer.Text, the application stops working. 
If i redirect the output to Console or anyother variable, the app work well.

So i'm guessing do gtk TextView.Buffer.Text can't 'accept' some chars ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending the text from a different thread, you need to use Gtk.Application.Invoke.  All updates to the UI must be done from the thread where Application.Run occurs.

Comment: Yes, i'm sending text from a different thread because i run a System Process.